# Dynamic updates and API - Bind or something else?

Tags: python, dns, bind

At place where I work we've few upcoming projects which require Dynamic-DNS functionality, eg. being able to dynamicaly insert/modify/delete DNS records.

So far we've been using simple Bind setup with one master and few slaves.  Master's data (zone files) are in git and we've simple but pretty effective Fabric file which we use to make sure all changes are committed to git and then to deploy changes to Master which propagates changes further to slaves.

We use views, we use them a lot and given how much internal stuff we've got, it's a must to keep this kind of functionality, i.e. to not expose internal records to public.

I've been researching possible solutions for quite a while which would **a** - allow us to perform dynamic updates on all zones including the same zones in different views, **b** - expose ideally restful API we can talk to to issue those updates, **c** - be open source so we can either use it or at least base on something.

Sadly I haven't found anything that's even close to this requirement set which I think is not very individual.  We started considering actually writing something on our own - use Python with Python DNS that will talk to Bind through nsupdate protocol and issue changes as we want but **before I dive in, I thought to get some advice whether I haven't missed anything ?**

Any advice, much appreciated.

Comment: When you already use `git`, why not simply get rid of the DNS slaves and make everything a master which is fed by its own `git` repository?

Comment: And then write simply some API that will edit the zone files directly, commit changes automatically and set up a post-commit hook which will deploy changes on commit to all DNS servers?

Comment: Yes. I'd write an ssh script which makes all servers pull the updates, though. Alternatively, the servers could pull every five minutes via `cron`; that might be enough.